# can't decode jwt token next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, jwt

i can't decode jwt token but i tried copying token and decode in jwt.io it's can decode

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export async function POST(request) {

    const formData = await request.formData();
    const paymentResponse = formData.get("paymentResponse");
    const paymentToken = paymentResponse;

    //console.log(formData);
    console.log(paymentToken);

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
        paymentToken,
        "mysecret",
        { algorithms: ["HS256"] }
    );

    console.log(decodedToken);

 
}
```

```
eyJsb2NhbGUiOm51bGwsImludm9pY2VObyI6IlRHNjQ2OCIsImNoYW5uZWxDb2RlIjoiQ0MiLCJyZXNwQ29kZSI6IjIwMDAiLCJyZXNwRGVzYyI6IlRyYW5zYWN0aW9uIGlzIGNvbXBsZXRlZCwgcGxlYXNlIGRvIHBheW1lbnQgaW5xdWlyeSByZXF1ZXN0IGZvciBmdWxsIHBheW1lbnQgaW5mb3JtYXRpb24uIn0=

- error JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at module.exports [as verify] (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:71:21)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/2c2p-response/frontend/route.js:31:78)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37)
```

i use the same code for decode in another function it's work i don't know why it's can't decode token

Comment: have you verify that the token value is not ```null``` ?

Comment: yes i verify it not null

Comment: Have you make sure that you use ```HS256``` algorithm when generate the token ?

Comment: yes I'm sure HS256

Comment: *eyJsb2NhbGUiOm51...* - what you posted here (the output of `console.log(paymentToken);`), is not a JWT. It's just a Base64 encoded JSON (could be the payload of part of a JWT, but it's not a valid JWT which has 3 parts separated by `.`.

Comment: sorry i don't know it's base64 can i decode base64 it's work ?

Comment: yes, it's not a valid JWT. We have to see how you generate the jwt and how you send it

Comment: yes, just normal Base64 that you can decode. And this string also ends with a `=`, which is used in Base64, but a JWT uses Base64Url encoding without padding.

Comment: i got it, Thank you so much everyone